# How to make TextBox required in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-10

i just started with development for the Windows 10 Platform and i can't figure out how to make the TextBox required in XAML so that it is not possible so save the data without adding a text.

Here is my .xaml file:

```
<Page
    x:Class="SessionTracker.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SessionTracker"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBox x:Name="nameInput" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" Margin="20,29,0,0" PlaceholderText="Spot Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150"/>
        <DatePicker x:Name="sessionDate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="20,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" />
        <Button x:Name="saveButton" FontSize="12" Content="save" Height="30" Margin="20,144,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_SaveSession"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

is there any way to make TextBox required?

Comment: What does "required" mean? Always include DatePicker in your pages or something else?

Comment: it means that it is not possible to save the data without adding a Date.

Comment: You can initially set `IsEnabled=False` on your button, and when you select a date (SelectionChanged) via `DatePicker`, set `IsEnabled` back to `true`.

Comment: thx! that's what i was looking for. But i recognized that the DatePicker is always set so i used the TextChanged event on the nameInput TextBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx [Kristian Vukusic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1332734/kristian-vukusic)! Setting `IsEnabled="False"` on the Button and then change it to `IsEnabled="True"` when a TextChanged event on the TextBox occurs works perfectly.